# Django creates the test database for Postgresql with incorrect sequences start values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-testing, django-postgresql

Using pyscopg2, as Django database default backend, and with very simple case for a test. It fails trying to create a user, with a **IntegrityError** exception

```
$ python manage.py test project.core.tests
nosetests --verbosity 1 project.core.tests --rednose
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
X.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) ERROR: Tests that a user with a sha1 hashed password is change to newer hash method

   Traceback (most recent call last):
    crowddeals/core/tests.py line 7 in setUp
      self.user1 = User.objects.create_user('user1', 'user1@domain.com')
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py line 160 in create_user
      user.save(using=self._db)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py line 477 in save
      force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py line 572 in save_base
      result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py line 203 in _insert
      return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py line 1588 in insert_query
      return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py line 911 in execute_sql
      cursor.execute(sql, params)
    env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py line 52 in execute
      return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
   IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_pkey"
   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

The *default* database is working, and is possible to add users. The tests fails just on the *test* database.

Looking at the *test* database, I see that the auto increment sequences for the primary keys for all tables has wrong start values, it takes the last used value from the *default* database as the start values on the *test* database.

For the default database, the User.id use the auto increment sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE auth_user_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

And for the test database creates

```
CREATE SEQUENCE auth_user_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 2
  CACHE 1;
```

This is obviously wrong, this happens also on other tables, as permissions.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE auth_permission_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 191
  CACHE 1;
```

I can't guess why this is happening, it has to create the sequences on the new test database starting from 1.

If I change the database engine backend to sqlite3, the exception don't happen. This just happens in postgresql.

How can I fix this? so my tests can start working again.

Comment: Do you clear the database before running each test?

Comment: If you mean the test database, is not created when running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't recreate the db with every test, then you've have to reset the sequences yourself.

Also, I think that the sequence definition you've posted were found when inspecting the db after the tests run with a db tool. In that case, I think your db tool is presenting you the SQL to create the sequence as it is: after it's been used.

The fact that it doesn't happen on sqlite has to do with it using a in-memory db by default. Therefore, it's being re-created in every test run.